# Accessing Hadoop with Python

Tags: python, hadoop

I am new to data engineering field and currently learning about Hadoop file system and  its uses. I want to perform few Hadoop commands from my python script that i could run so that all the hdfs commands get executed in a sequence. The job that i want to perform are:

1. copy a file from local to hdfs
2. download a file from hdfs to local
3. Read various kinds of file such as text,avro,csv and parquet files stored in hdfs.

I want all of these tasks to be performed from a python script and not by typing the respective commands from the terminal. Do help me out and please let me know if some library or module exists with which i can perform this.

Hadoop version is 3.2.1, python version is 3.8.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you consider using [Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html).(Python for big data)  It natively works with HDFS, and the mentioned file formats.  (It is typically a big data tool.)
Python is (generally) *small* data tool and doesn't really work well with the size of files that are typically in HDFS.

I'm not judging python as a poor choice, only denoting that it's *target* data profile is data that fits in the memory of 1 computer.

Comment: If you found my question helpful please upvote it.  If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: _Python is a small data tool_. I don't really agree with this; e.g. I've seen large Pandas dataframes, and Dask exists as well. Subsequently, Spark can also be used for small, distributed datasets without large HDFS  files

Comment: Good Points, I feel I did qualify my judgment that it's "Target data profile", not that it's a hard rule, but a target.  In this particular use case pyspark seems the right tool.

Comment: @MattAndruff i did upvote, but as my account is fairly new, it doesn't show up. Need 15 reputations.